# How can I use device bonding and dhcp to bind a WiFi and NIC to the same DHCP address?

Tags: networking, ethernet, dhcp, network-bonding

I have a notebook that has both a Wired (`enxa0cec80070b7`) and a WiFi adapter (`wlp1s0`)

I use my router’s reserved address feature to assign a DHCP address to each device

```
172.16.68.13: wlp1s0
172.16.68.14: enxa0cec80070b7
```

This machine will be moved back and forth to a different network (and others) that will have 172.16.71.1 as its gateway.

In `/etc/bash.bashrc` I have this snippet which will set an environment variable called `SERVER_IP` which is used by various services.

```
IP="$(ip addr show enxa0cec80070b7 | awk '$1 == "inet" { print $2 }' | cut -d/ -f1)"
export SERVER_IP=${IP}
```

Assume I use the router to always assign .13 and .14, regardless of what network the machine is on.

I would always like to be able to use the .14 IP address, even if it’s not connected —- and if it’s not to use the .13 as backup, which should always be connected.

*Is this possible?*

Comment: This sounds like an XY problem. What makes you think that device bonding is the right solution (hint: it isn't). How is the default route (what you call "gateway") relevant anyway? What are the netmasks of the two networks?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with bonding: bonding will use *both*  adapters at all time and `bond` their separate addresses together into one (different) IP address.

Furthermore: if the machine does not have any statically linked IP addresses, but reserved DHCP IP addresses only, you'd have to configure *all* the networks you'd *ever* connect to to make this work in a reliable way.

So I'm going to tell you what I told the Finance Director of some company I worked for 20 years ago:

> No, we cannot change all of our servers in the large server room by a bunch of laptops stacked together one on top of the other in a broom closet.  There is a reason that servers are more expensive than a laptop.

#### Sorry! ¯\_(ツ)_/¯